# getting this error when running a random forest model

Tags: r, random-forest

This is the error:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  object '.data_Holand.Netherlands' not found
```

This is my code when I run it:

```
rf2<-randomForest(income~., data = income_df_train2, importance= TRUE)
income_df_test2$.data_.Holand.Netherlands<-rep(0, times = nrow(income_df_test2))
predicted<-predict(rf2, newdata = income_df_test2, type = "prob") ####This line does not work need to check why
ID<-income_df_test$Id
```

I already ran this model previously using training data, now I am running it against the test data to produce a csv file with the results.

Comment: Can you check the `colnames(income_df_test2)`

Answer (score 0):

Please take the time to understand and investigate error messages before posting. The error says `.data_Holand.Netherlands` was not found. This means it does not exist in the testing dataframe. And it does not. You have created the column `.data_.Holand.Netherlands` instead of `.data_Holand.Netherlands`.